# Tomcat doesn't run if "metadata-complete" is set as false

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, metadata

I'm using Eclipse for Java EE developers. I'm trying to run this servlet:

```
package br.com.caelum.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebInitParam;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;



@WebServlet(
          name = "OiServlet3",
          urlPatterns = {"/oi"},
          initParams = {
            @WebInitParam(name = "param1", value = "value1"),
            @WebInitParam(name = "param2", value = "value2")}
          )
    public class OiMundo extends HttpServlet {
        protected void service (HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        // escreve o texto
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Primeira Servlet</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");

        ServletConfig config = getServletConfig();

        String parameter1= config.getInitParameter("param1");
        out.println("Value of parameter 1: " + parameter1);

        String parameter2 = config.getInitParameter("param2");
        out.println("<br>Value of parameter 2: " + parameter2);

        out.println("<h1>Hi Servlet!</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");

        out.close();


    }
}
```

If I set `metadata-complete="false"` (or don't set it) at the web.xml file, I got this error when trying to start Tomcat:

```
'Publishing to Tomcat v8.0 at Locahost...' has  encountered a problem.
Publishing the configuration...
```

I I set it to `true`, it runs. However, it is printed:

```
value of parameter 1: null
value of parameter 2: null
```

Because the annotation was ignored (that's what happens when you set metada-complete to true).

help!

Comment: you had a typo in `Locahost`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check all again (`web.xml` especially). With empty `metadata-complete`, I run your code:

```
package br.com.caelum.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebInitParam;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(
        name = "OiServlet3",
        urlPatterns = {"/oi"},
        initParams = {
                @WebInitParam(name = "param1", value = "value1"),
                @WebInitParam(name = "param2", value = "value2")}
)
public class OiMundo extends HttpServlet {
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        // escreve o texto
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Primeira Servlet</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        ServletConfig config = getServletConfig();
        String parameter1 = config.getInitParameter("param1");
        out.println("Value of parameter 1: " + parameter1);
        String parameter2 = config.getInitParameter("param2");
        out.println("<br>Value of parameter 2: " + parameter2);
        out.println("<h1>Hi Servlet!</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
        out.close();
    }

}
```

no problem, it works:
[image]

Comment: My web.xml file had already an specification of URLPattern, which was getting into conflict with the @WebServlet annotation!